# Mostrar la ruta de un archivo, antes de subirla a un servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo este código el cual le asigna nombre a mi archivo a subir a mi servidor, esto es para darlo de alta.

```
string rutaPDF = Request.MapPath("PDFs_Landing/");
 Random ra = new Random();
 int numeroP = r.Next(5, 10000000);
 tituloLanzamiento = tituloLanzamiento.Replace(" ", "_");
 if (Directory.Exists(rutaPDF) == false)
     Directory.CreateDirectory(rutaPDF);
 string documento = Path.GetFileName(urlPdf.FileName);
 string extensionP = Path.GetExtension(documento);
 documento = documento.Substring(documento.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
 documento = "Documento_" + numeroP + '_' + Pais + extensionP;
 urlPdf.SaveAs(rutaPDF + documento);
 string urlPDF = "/Landing_Page/PDFs_Landing/" + archivo;
 nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace("_", " ");
```

Lo que quiero es que antes de dar de alta me muestre la ruta de destino para poder copiarla. 
Vi un ejemplo el cual lo implemente así:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="custom-input-file required">
    <input type="file" name="urlPdf" id="urlPdf" class="input-file" onchange="ValidarDocumento(this);" required />
    <label id="errorDoc"></label>
    PDF&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-file text-info"></i>
    <div class="archivo">Click para elegir...</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Mostrar Url de Destino</a>
</div>
```

Y esto

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p>
                    Ruta de la imagen del párrafo desde el que se ha hecho click en el modal:
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
  $('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(){
    var urlPdf = $(this).prev('input').attr('file');

    $($(this).data('target')+' .modal-header p').html(urlPdf);
  });
</script>
```

Pero no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Revisa muy bien tus variables, ya que algunas no se muestran definidas. Para ser exacto la variable de `string urlPDF = "/Landing_Page/PDFs_Landing/" + **archivo**;`

Ahora tu verdadero problema es como ingeniarte para tomar tu url y mostrarla en el modal y después de eso que enviar la url para guardar el archivo generado.

Comment: un gran problema jajaja